# api call get failed, CORS, nginx is confiured

Tags: angular, nginx, .net-core, cors, reverse-proxy

hello and thank you for your time

i have a dotnet core web api application running on port 6000 and an angular application, using nginx i reverse proxied https://api.asoode.com to donet core application, and https://panel.asoode.com to angular application

nginx configuration for dotnet core application is:

```
location / {
    root   /home/asoode/api;
    proxy_pass         http://45.82.138.126:6000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'panel.asoode.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }

    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'panel.asoode.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

    }

    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'panel.asoode.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    }

}
```

i have used wildcard, domain with and without protocol, still im getting CORS error, [image]

when i request the api using postman and OPTION method, i get this result, which shows that panel.asoode.com is ALLOWED!!!!!! [image]

Answer (score -1):

i had 2 mistakes and mostly it was my fault becase the error message was saying the value provided was not valid,

1- needed protocol
2- my client application was using a "custom header" name for authorize and i didnt know i had to put it there